# Retrofit taking too long for DNS resolution

Tags: android, https, dns, retrofit2

I am using retrofit to make a rest call to "https:/google.com". The first request is taking too long.

I tried searching on the net to find a solution, but I was not able to find any.

Below is the code snippet:

```
    String baseURL1 = "https://google.com";
    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .eventListener(new PrintingEventListener())
                .build();
    Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseURL1).client(httpClient)
            .build();
    TestInterface testInterface = client.create(TestInterface.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> testCall = testInterface.testCall();

    System.out.println("Scanning REQUEST 1 (new connection)");
    testCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.i( TAG, "Scanning apiCall end success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i( TAG, "Scanning apiCall end failed");
        }});
```

I am using the latest version of retrofit:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0'
```

The log statements with EventListener:

```
REQUEST 1 (new connection)
0.000 callStart
0.007 dnsStart
5.048 dnsEnd
5.049 connectStart
5.056 secureConnectStart
5.106 secureConnectEnd
5.108 connectEnd
5.109 connectionAcquired
5.110 requestHeadersStart
5.112 requestHeadersEnd
5.196 responseHeadersEnd
5.197 responseBodyStart
REQUEST 1 (new connection) end success
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check your Internet connection and DNS server's used by the device you are running the above code. 
Try to run the dns resolution for `google.com` using another DNS resolver client, and see if it is really the issue with retrofit. As i am guessing its not at retrofit level but your network level.

Comment: I was able to solve this by using google's public dns resolver as stated [here](https://garage.easytaxi.com/tag/dns-android-okhttp/).